# Trouble with Parenting Dress and Bag to a Model

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, rigging, parent

I'm having some issues with attaching a dress and a bag to a moving figure. I created a dress and attached it to a human figure, and am pleased with the final result. However, when I parent the dress to the armature, there are a few vertices that don't move with it. See image below.

[image]

I also am unable to get the bag to move with the model. When I parent the bag to the armature, the body of the bag gets displaced, and only the body responds to armature movement. I have tried parenting the bag with different settings (don't use automatic weights, parent it to the mesh of the human figure and not the armature) to no avail.

Any help with these problems / tips / ways I can generally improve my layout are greatly appreciated!

The blender file: [image]